# TSLint throwing warning

Tags: gulp, tslint

My `tslint.json` looks like the following

```
{
    "defaultSeverity": "error",
    "extends": [
        "tslint:recommended"
    ],
    "jsRules": {},
    "rules": {},
    "rulesDirectory": []
}
```

My gulp file has a task named `tslint` which looks like:

```
gulp.task('tslint', function() {
    return gulp.src(lintFiles)
        .pipe(tslint({
            formatter: "verbose"
        }))
        .pipe(tslint.report());
});
```

When I run `gulp tslint`, it throws me the following warning

> Following rules specified in configuration couldn't be applied to .js or .jsx files:
>
> no-reference-import
>
> Make sure to exclude them from "jsRules" section of your tslint.json.

In order to exclude I changed `"jsRules": {},` to `"jsRules": {"no-reference-import": false }`, still no change and I got the same warning. I googled about it and could not find anything. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with the current version of `tslint 5.0.0`. The issue has been referenced [here](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/2440). You can go back to a previous version of tslint as a workaround until the issue is fixed.